# Firebase security rule error

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, nosql

I am trying to implement some firebase security rules at firebase console. Basically, I have a receipt item and it consists of receipt ID and item ID. I am trying to implement a rule to check if both ID exists before insert.

My table structure for receipts:

```
receipts {
    accountID {
        receiptID {}
    }
}
```

Table structure for items:

```
items {
    itemID {}
}
```

Table structure for receipt items:

```
receiptItems {
    receiptItemID {
        itemID, receiptID
    }
}
```

What I have achieved so far:

```
"receiptItems": {
    "$receiptItemID" : {
        "$receiptID" : {
            ".validate": "root.child('receipts/' + $receiptID).exists()"
         },
         "$itemID" : {
            ".validate": "root.child('items/' + $itemID).exists()"
         }
    }
}
```

However, this leads to an error message saying cannot have multiple default rules. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, those rules are indeed invalid: it is unclear what validation it should apply to what child. But I'm not sure I understand the JSON you're trying to validate. Can you edit your question to ensure the first three JSON snippets are the valid JSON you want to have in the database?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen For example, I wanted to check if the receiptID and itemID which I am going to insert into receiptItems table existed under receipts and items table respectively before adding them. The structure for receiptID is receipt -> accountID -> receiptID. Those IDs are the unique push ID. I am trying to simplify the structure by removing unrelevant details for the ease of reading

Comment: Can you edit your question to ensure the first three JSON snippets are the valid JSON you want to have in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got this one but your JSON structure is a bit unclear so let me provide my interpretation.

```
items
  item_0
    item_data: "some data about item 0"
  item_1
    item_data: "some data about item 1"

receipts
  receipt_0
    receipt_data: "data about receipt 0"
  receipt_1
    receipt_data: "data about receipt 1"

receipt_items
  receipt_item_0
    item_id: "item_0"
    receipt_id: "recept_0
```

now suppose I want to write a new receipt_item node for item 1, receipt 1, which would look like this:

```
  receipt_item_1
    item_id: "item_1"
    receipt_id: "recept_1
```

The rules need to validate item_1 exists in the items node and that receipt_1 exists in the receipt node.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "receipt_items": {
      "$ri": {
        ".validate": "root.child('items').child( newData.child('item_id').val() ).exists()
        &&
        .validate": "root.child('receipts').child( newData.child('receipt_id').val() ).exists()"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

note the validate rule is one long string "..&&.." - I broke it up on three lines for readability

Going from the inside out:

```
newData.child('item_id').val()
```

gets the value of the incoming data child node 'item_id' which in this case is item_1

```
root.child('receipts').child( 'item_1' ).exists()
```

check to see if root/receipts/item_1 exists

The same concepts apply for validating the receipt_id

Comment: yeah that is what I am trying to do! But for the receipts right, I got there level which is receipts -> accountID -> receiptID. So for the .Validate, should it become root.child('receipts/some accountID here‘)?

Comment: I would say no because the accountID isn't being stored in the receipt_items node so the rules wouldn't have access or any way to know what that is. More importantly; if each account can have multiple receipts like acct_0/rec_0, acct_0/rec_1 and then acct_1/rec_0, acct_1/rec_1 what differentiates rec_0 in acct_0 and rec_0 in acct_1? i.e you can have multiple receipts in each account.

Comment: Ahh I see I see. So the solution above is sufficient?

Comment: @guest176969 It works for me! I would suggest altering your /receipts structure to match what I suggested - if you need to store which account the receipt goes with, just add it as a child node; like /receipts/account_id. Try it and if this answer helped make sure to accept it so it can help others.

Comment: I see I see but let's say with my structure above, the suggested solution also works right? because I have built for quite some codes based on the structure already so it would took quite much changes if I were to change the structure for now

Comment: @guest176969 Unfortunately it won't won't work as is because the receipt is inside a accountID parent. When you are writing data to the receipt_items node, notice that accountID isn't being written to that node so there wouldn't be a way to reference from the data being written. i.e. the data being written only contains item_id and receipt_id. However, if you can write the account_id along with that data then the rule could be modified to work using something like newData.child('account_id').child('receipt_id')

Comment: let's say I wanted to check for items now. Let's forget about the receipt and account. Is my solution in the question correct way to define it?

Comment: @guest176969 If you remove the receipt validation, that rule works for the receiptItemId child node. *However* it allows *any* other data to be written to the receiptItems node. Try it in the Firebase Console rules simulator; I set the location to /receiptItems and the Data (JSON) to "some_key": "some value" and it allows that write. You may want to consider altering your structure for better security or perhaps add more validation.

Comment: Sorry but what do you meant by "some_key": "some value"? Do you mean writing any value that is not existed in the receipts table onto receiptID attribute?

Comment: @guest176969 That meant to test your rules, in the Firebase Console rules simulator, I literally put *some_key* for the key and *some_value* for the value to see if that would get written to the *receiptItemId* node, which it did. That's why I mentioned it may be a security issue: while your security rules work for the child node within *receiptItemId*, any other data could be written directly to the *receiptItemId* node, hence your rules having a possible security or data corruption issue.